# Passing argument to Class method

Tags: c#, sql, arguments

I have problem with passing argument to class. I want to pass every iteration which will fill the array.

```
private string[,] links;

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                links = sql.Link(i);
            }
```

And that's the method inside another class:

```
public string[,] Link(int i)
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    string[,] array = new string[40,40];
    int num = 0;
    sqlCommand.Connection = this.conn;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (40) Link FROM dbo.Links";
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        array[i,num] = sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();                        
        num++;
    }
    sqlDataReader.Close();
    return array;
}
```

The thing is, that the `Links` array contains only nulls.

When I change passing code to:

```
links = sql.Link(0);
```

Then every index from `0,0` to `0,39` is properly filled. But why passing does not work properly?

Comment: Are you sure, check links[39,0]..[39,39] after the I<40 loop. What are you trying to do, why execute the same Sql 40 times?

Answer (score 0):

Because, in the following line

`string[,] array = new string[40,40];`
you are generating a new array and returning the same.

So during first iteration of the for loop, in `links = sql.Link(i);` links array will contain values for links[0, 0] through links[0, 39], but in the next iteration, as new array object is returned, links will now point to this new object (which will hold values for [1, 0] through [1, 39]).

In your current case, after the for lop is completed, your links array variable contains values for [39, 0] through [39, 39] but not others.

***Possible approaches***

The solution is to get an array and merge it with the previous one.
Two approaches are shown below for reference:

**1) Returning array for an index in one iteration and then merge with previous data**

```
private string[,] links = links[40, 40];

for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    string[] linksPart = Link(i);

    for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
    {
        links[i, j] = linksPart[j];
    }
    // here, your links array variable contain values from [0, 0] through [40, 40]

    //...rest of the code.
}

string[] Link(int i)
{
    string[] linkParts = new string[40];

    //connection open and populate array code goes here
}
```

**2) Passing the array as a parameter to Link function**

```
private string[,] links = links[40, 40];

for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    Link(i, links);

    // here, your links array variable contain values from [0, 0] through [40, 40]

    //...rest of the code.
}

string[] Link(int i, string[,] arr)
{
    // no need to create a new array

    //connection open and other code (before sqlDataReader.Read() line)
    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
       arr[i , num] = sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString(); 
       num++;
    }

    //rest of the code and return statement
}
```